# How to find k nearest values in a pandas data frame column to an input value x in O(logn)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sorting, binary-search-tree

I have a data frame with two columns: 1) ID: random integer numbers which represent sample IDs, 2) A: float numbers

```
size_df1 = 1000
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_sample((size_df1)), columns=list('A'))
df1['ID'] = random.sample(range(0, size_df1), size_df1)
```

Given an input like x=0.21, how to find 10 (or any other integer such as k) nearest values in `df1['A']` to x, in log(n) where n is the number of rows in df1. Note, this should be done without replacement and each time that I find these 10 nearest values in `df1['A']`, I am supposed to remove these values or somehow mark them and not use them for the next x. Can this be solved in logn at all? Thanks

Comment: You can take a look at [`searchsorted`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.searchsorted.html), which will require your data frame being pre sorted. That adds an `nlog(n)` overhead. But all later look ups will be `log(n)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily find the k smallest values with [`.nsmallest()`](https://devdocs.io/pandas%7E1/reference/api/pandas.series.nsmallest), and the closest values are the ones with the smallest absolute difference:

```
>>> (df1['A'] - 0.21).abs().nsmallest(10)
969    0.000014
889    0.000442
779    0.003299
259    0.003637
843    0.003700
84     0.003818
651    0.004264
403    0.004360
648    0.004421
543    0.005088
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

You can then reuse the indexes of this if you want to access the matching rows:

```
>>> df1.loc[(df1['A'] - 0.21).abs().nsmallest(10).index]
            A   ID
969  0.210014  237
889  0.210442  225
779  0.206701  127
259  0.213637  883
843  0.206300  330
84   0.206182   17
651  0.205736   64
403  0.205640  388
648  0.214421  964
543  0.204912  616
```

Note that the doc of `nsmallest` says:

> Faster than .sort_values().head(n) for small n relative to the size of the Series object.

A word on complexity, since your values aren’t sorted:

- the bare minimum complexity is `O(n)` if you want to find the 1 closest value
- you could do a binary-search-like to get `O(log(n))`, but that requires sorting first − so it’s in fact `O(n log(n))`.

---

Suppose your dataframe is sorted on A:

```
>>> df1.sort_values('A', inplace=True)
```

Then we can try to use the sorted search function, which returns the row number (not index value):

```
>>> df1['A'].searchsorted(0.21)
197
```

This means we can use that to find the `k` closest candidate and then use our previous method on this `2k` dataframe:

```
def find_closest(df, val, k):
    return df.loc[df['A'].sub(val).abs().nsmallest(k).index]

def find_closest_sorted(df, val, k):
    closest = df['A'].searchsorted(val)
    if closest < k:
        return find_closest(df.iloc[:closest + k], val, k)

    return find_closest(df.iloc[closest - k:closest + k], val, k)
```

```
>>> find_closest_sorted(df1, 0.21, 10)
            A   ID
969  0.210014  237
889  0.210442  225
779  0.206701  127
259  0.213637  883
843  0.206300  330
84   0.206182   17
651  0.205736   64
403  0.205640  388
648  0.214421  964
543  0.204912  616
```

The complexity should be here:

- `O(n log(n))` for sorting (which can be amortized over many lookups)
- `O(log(n))` for the sorted search
- `O(k)` for the final step.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I will try the ```nsmallest``` and will let you know how much it will help. BTW, is there any library in python I can use for the binary search in a sorted array A?

Comment: There you @khemedi I’ve added a solution for sorted arrays

Comment: you solution with ```searchsorted``` is super useful. Question tho, what is the motivation behind using the ```find_closest``` function, if we already find ```closest``` and can easily  return ```closets + k/2``` and ```closets - k/2``` in ```find_closest_sorted ```?

Comment: Another thing is that although very helpful but I'm not sure if your proposed solution matches without replacement, does it? For example if I call ```find_closest_sorted``` for the same ```val``` it is going to return the same outputs. Do you think it will work if I add another column 'MATCHED', ```df1['MATCHED']=0``` and then replace ```df1``` and ```df``` in your code with ```df1[df1['MATCHED']==0]``` and ```df[df['MATCHED']==0]```?

Comment: @khemedi you don’t know whether the nearest values are all below, all above, or more equally spread around the value you’re searching for. You just know they can’t be more than `k` away in a sorted interval. The solution does not match with replacement: that would mean returning `k` times the closest element.

Comment: Wow that was smart, thanks! Yes I agree, I do need both functions. Regarding my other question, I need to put the ```find_closest_sorted ``` inside a loop each time with a different ```val``` and each time that the ```find_closest_sorted ``` returns the k-nearest values to the ```val``` I want it to remove those k-nearest values and not consider them in the next iteration that I call ```find_closest_sorted ```. I tried dropping the k-nearest values from ```df1``` using ```df.drop(nearest.index)``` after each time I call ```nearest=find_closest_sorted (...)```, but it makes the code so slow.

Comment: That’s how I would do it @khemedi. I think if you need that faster you should make a different question, because it possibly would be very different solutions, using a mask or something like that.

Comment: Thanks you! I will run and see if it ends in a reasonably short time first.

Comment: FYI- I added a new column to the data frame ```df1['MATCHED']=0``` and each time I call the function like ```nearest=find_closest_sorted(df1[df1['MATCHED']==0], 0.21, 10)``` and then after finding the nearest point I call ```df1.loc[nearest.index, 'MATCHED'] = 1``` before I start another iteration. It seems to be working fine.